# Is there are a way to restore System schema to it's original state?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, system-tables

I've installed Oracle 11g Database Enterprise Edition and my task was to import schemas. I'm totally new so I ran command:

```
imp system/password file=path.dmp full=y
```

And import everything (10 dumps, 150+ tables) into System schema. Could I restore this Schema to original state without reinstalling database? Or maybe you could delete directory with all of this tables and reinstall database, without harming listeners and `tnsnames.ora`?

Comment: That's a 'full' import - what makes you think it has only affected the system schema? Note that objects owned by SYS and SYSTEM [aren't exported in a full export](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1463976400346989259#4847976800346324066). Do you have backups?

Comment: Nope, no backups. I've worked with Postgres and there you could always recreate database, when you've done something wrong. I don't know what it affected, but I have a lot of useless tables when I log in with SYSTEM user. Maybe it affects other stuff, but I don't know.

Comment: Do you mean you want to go back to an empty database? You can [drop and create](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/create.htm) databases. What are these 'useless' tables (please give an example), I'm concerned they may not be as useless as you think.

Comment: Yes, I want to restore an empty database. And I've recreated it already, but I thought that there may be command for restoration system schemas. But I think there are no such option. Useless tables are tables, that should be in different schemas, but imported in system schema.

Comment: The question remains why those tables were imported in the system schema (or do you mean the system tablespace?). What were they doing in the system schema in the first place before the export?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to restore SYSTEM schema to the original state of empty database if you haven't backups, so you should recreate database. You could do this with Database Configuration Assistant (I'm using Windows Server 2012): run it, select delete database option, select database you want to delete, enter password to dba user and execute it.

After this you could recreate database with options you need.

Comment: Backups aren't for getting back to an empty database, use DBCA as you say or `DROP/CREATE DATABASE`.